# Error with return None instead Objectid in Mongoengine query

Tags: python, flask-mongoengine

I do not know why my query with exist documents does not return id instead of None value

```
class FinItem(db.Document): # luu cac hang muc
  item_code = db.StringField(max_length=30)
  item_name = db.StringField(max_length=200)
  ....
```

When I use the query to fetch all documents like that:

```
fin = FinItem.obejcts()
for f in fin:
   print f.id
```

It returns all **None** even I have the documents in my database.

Comment: `FinItem.objects.all()` (with `je`)

Comment: @KlausD. You can make it more clearly, I am a little bit confused with the "je" in your comment.

Comment: You had a typo in it.

Comment: Thanks for your support but it does not error with typo even I try with the right keyword ('objects'). It is only wrong when I type to post this problem.